# I want to create a batch file

Tags: tomcat, restart

How to create a batch file which has both startup.bat and shutdown.bat in a single file and restart the tomcat in windows . I haven't tried yet am new to the tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file with following content.

```
call shutdown.bat & 
startup.bat
PAUSE
```

- `&` allows to execute `startup.bat` even if Tomcat is not running and `shutdown.bat` fails.
- Change paths of `shutdown.bat` and `startup.bat` according to your paths, I have assumes this restartt bat to be in tomcat/bin folder